# Move-Item to correct Destination

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

## The Script:

1. Creates a list of folders based on the filenames in the scripts root directory, each folder breaks down the name by "Year/Month/Day"
2. Moves each file to the designated folder

#### Error Message:

```
 CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: 
(S:\Data\TECHNOL...59_20180108.txt:String) 
[Move-Item], ItemNotFoundException FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

## My Issue

The files will not move to the correct endpath

```
#Create Directory
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
$rootPath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
cd $rootPath
$FileNameArray = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.txt"
$FileNameArray = $FileNameArray -replace "....$"
$FileNameArray = $FileNameArray -replace "^59_"

Foreach($f in $FileNameArray)
{
        $Year = $f -replace "^\d{0}|\d{4}$" #"....$"
        $Month = $f -replace "^\d{4}|\d{2}$"
        $Month = $Month | sort -Unique
        $Day = $f -replace "^\d{6}|\d{0}$"
        #Loop 2a
        Foreach($m1 in $Month){
        #Loop 2a-a
            Foreach($d1 in $Day){
                Move-Item -Path ($rootPath + '\59_' + $file + '.txt') 
-Destination ($rootPath + '\' + $Year + '\' + $m1 + '\' + $d1)
                }
        }
}
```

Apologies for the spaghetti code & simple question, I am new to both Computer Science and PowerShell.

Comment: Where does $file come from?

Comment: It was the old name for the $f, let me change that & try running it.

Comment: It worked thanks EBGreen!

Comment: Using `-WhatIf` on the `Move-Item` cmdlet can make testing these things must easier.

Comment: Probably good to add `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to ensure that a directory is not included. I know, who in their right mind would name a directory with `.txt` at the end. It could happen. Practice defensive coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script has two security features:

1. The `MD` command has a trailing `-confirm` you have to answer
2. The `Move-Item` has a `-WhatIf` which shows what would be done without the Parameter

If the script works OK, remove them both.

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\05\03\SO_50158185.ps1
Set-StrictMode -Version 2
$rootPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
cd $rootPath

Get-ChildItem "59_20[0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9].txt" |
  Where-Object {$_.BaseName -Match '59_(?<year>\d{4})(?<Month>\d{2})(?<Day>\d{2})'}|
    ForEach-Object {
      $DestDir = Join-Path $rootPath ("{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $Matches.Year,$Matches.Month,$Matches.Day)
      If (!(Test-Path $DestDir)) {MD $DestDir -Confirm| Out-Null}
      $_ | Move-Item -Destination $DestDir -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out guys! Just needed to change $file to $f. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: So you know in future, avoid posting an answer if it's not actually an answer. Add it as a comment instead.